# Automatically converting a raw ElasticSearch query to NEST DSL query?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I've seen a lot of questions around here regarding how to convert a specific raw ElasticSearch query to an equivalent NEST query. My team and I often find ourselves converting a Kibana-generated request string to a NEST query so we can use it in our application.

My question is, is there any automatic way out there that can successfully perform such a conversion?

ie:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

to:

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<Project>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .MatchAll()
    )
);
```

If not, is there any reason why there cannot be? It seems like it would all be governed by a set of rules, which would be essentially a reverse engineering effort of how the NEST client uses a low level request under the hood (which would aid testability as well).

I know this would be a large undertaking, but I would like to at least make a start on such an application if it would be feasible.

Comment: There is nothing to do this currently. The topic has been discussed several times before, but an implementation has not been started

Comment: @RussCam thanks for the reply. Can you identify any major blocks that I'd run into if I took this on? The plan would be to start small, and add support gradually.